# can I query select the Parent from child in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

how to use querySelector to select the parent element from the child?

in my example the HTML structure is like this:

```html
<label>
  <input/> <!-- I know only this -->
</label>
```

and in html what I know is **only** the **child** so `input`.

how can get the parent from child input, so getting the `label`.

---

from what I know is easy to get the child from the parent by doing like this `parent > child`

is there any `child < parent`? (similar logic).

---

if isn't possible with `querySelector()` is there any other way with the javascript API?

Comment: See [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: @Ouroborus I think this is best than the js solution! thanks, because is native selector

Comment: @stackdeveloper yes is good solution also this, but isn't supported for now, at least firefox/IE and chrome from the latest versions (105+). try see here https://caniuse.com/?search=has , maybe use it in the future when it will be supported. but is better if is work for your target of users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.parentElement` or use `.closest()`

> **parentElement:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement
>
> > if you want only the parent element.
>
> **closest:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
>
> > if you want specific tag (this can make you some bugs if not used properly)

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

// you get the same result with these 2
console.log(input.parentElement)

console.log(input.closest("label"))

// you can use all the method of element 
// like style, classList, etc...

input.parentElement.style.outline = "0.2rem solid red";
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text" /> <!-- I know only this -->
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can get input element, after get parent with function [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```js
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
var label = inputElement.closest('label');
console.log(label)
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text" /> <!-- I know only this -->
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

get the element by the input tag and then look for its `parent`. However, be sure to check for the undefined and multiple query results from the below code snippet.

```
document.querySelector("input").parentElement
```